# Calculus 1- Find directly the derivative of a function f.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The following limit represents the derivative of a function $f$ at a point $a$. Evaluate the limit.

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0 } \frac{\sin^2\left(\frac\pi 4+h \right)-\frac 1 2} h$$

Comment: L'Hospital? ${}$

Comment: Looks like he is supposed to use the limit definition of a derivative. I would conjecture that L'Hospital is a bit too advanced if he's intended to use the limit definition.

Answer (score 2):

Write the limit as

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{2{{\sin }^2}\left( {\frac{\pi }{4} + h} \right) - 1}}{{2h}}$$

Now use  $$2{\sin ^2}x - 1 =  - \cos \left( {2x} \right)$$

Thus

$$=\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{-\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }{2} + 2h} \right)}}{{2h}}$$

$$ =   \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{\sin \left( {2h} \right)}}{{2h}} =   1$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\sin^2x$. We have, $f^{\prime}(x)=2\sin x\cos x$. In the other hand
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lll}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+h\right)-\frac{1}{2}}{h}&=&\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+h\right)-f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{h}\\
&=&f^{\prime}(\pi/2)\\
&=&2\sin(\pi/4)\cos(\pi/4)\\
&=&2(1/\sqrt{2})(1/\sqrt{2})=1.
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the hint as asking you to identify the function and where the derivative is taken. There are a couple of natural choices.

If you let $f(x)=\sin^2(\pi/4+x)$, your limit expression, directly from the definition of derivative, is $f'(0)$. Now calculate $f'(x)$ using the ordinary rules of differentiation, and find $f'(0)$.

Or else let $f(x)=\sin^2 x$. Then our limit is the derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=\pi/4$.

Comment: I think he is trying to find the derivative *using* the limit.

Comment: @Navin: It is possible. My read of the question goes the other way. If we take the interpretation that you make, there is a good answer by Peter Tamaroff.